# MYSQL: How to get rows inserted in the last X hours without querying the entire table

Tags: mysql, performance

Let's say I have a table with 1 million rows and in the last 2 hours only 5 rows were added (each day different number of rows are being added per hour).

I want to be able to get the rows which were added in the past 2 hours for example. What is the best query / implementation I could use for optimal performance.

I'm tying to avoid querying the entire 1 million table and compare dates every 2 hours... is there a better way?

Thank you.

Comment: How does a row look like? Do you have increment id? timestamp on create? Any index?

Comment: use index on the columns you want filter

Comment: Please read this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/ Then [edit] your question if you want ansers that aren't pure guesses.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have any table yet, I asked the question in order to understand how to structure it for best performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following table with more than a million rows:

```
CREATE TABLE `event` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`data` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`occured_on` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1058669 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Note:** there is no index on the `occured_on` field.

To get the rows inserted in the last 2 hours, you would write:

```
SELECT * FROM `event` WHERE `occured_on` > NOW() - INTERVAL 2 HOUR;
```

But if you profile the query,

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `event` WHERE occured_on > NOW() - INTERVAL 2 HOUR;
```

you would get something like this (depends on your data):

```
id  select_type TABLE   TYPE    possible_keys   KEY     key_len ref     ROWS    Extra
1   SIMPLE      event   ALL     NULL            NULL    NULL    NULL    1053588 USING where
```

This basically means full table scan (ROWS entry tell us how many rows MySQL had to look at to find the result set). 
Now if you add index and run the same explain query,

```
ALTER TABLE `event` ADD INDEX (`occured_on`);
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `event` WHERE occured_on > NOW() - INTERVAL 2 HOUR;
```

you would see (depends on your data):

```
id  select_type TABLE   TYPE    possible_keys   KEY         key_len ref     ROWS    Extra
1   SIMPLE      event   RANGE   occured_on      occured_on  6       NULL    5       USING INDEX condition
```

This means that MySQL only looked at 5 rows to find the result set. As you can see indexes matter a lot.

Comment: (The "5" is 'approximate.  But a lot better than "1053588".)

Answer (score 1):

To put a finer point to @Eric's comment/question: show us your schema.

But the short answer is that without trickery involving the query log and other "out-of-band" logic with the database server, not likely.

However, thinking like this entirely misses the point of Relational Database Management Systems (RDBMS).  Running queries against "the whole" table is what SQL is about.  In line with that, provided you have a properly specified schema, running SELECTs with restrictive WHERE clauses in a performant manner is one of the primary value-adds of an RDBMS over, say, a text file.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE last_update > NOW() - INTERVAL 2 HOUR;
```

Provided a column like `last_update` exists, has the proper datatype, and an index, that query will run *very* fast.  A million rows to sort through?  Not a thing.  A billion rows to sort through?  No problem.  I regularly run such queries on billion row tables, and get sub-second results on medium grade desktop hardware.

The key to this speed?  Proper schemas, proper normalization, and appropriate use of indexes.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.